# ¿Cómo recorrer un ArrayList y terminar cuando quiera?

Tags: java, arraylist, while

En este problema estoy creando un ArrayList de productos de abarrotes, y quiero pedirle al usuario que ingrese el abarrote que desea y que si este coincide con uno del ArrayList que pregunte por la cantidad que desea para luego preguntar por otro y así sucesivamente hasta que desee finalizar. Imagino que es con un while pero no logro realizarlo, además tengo problemas a la hora de recorrer el ArrayList porque este me lee 3 veces lo que planteo.

```
package productos;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Compras {

public static void main(String[] args){
ArrayList<Abarrotes> abarrotes = new ArrayList<>(); 
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


Abarrotes producto1 = new Abarrotes(1000,"Arroz",1300, 1000);
Abarrotes producto2 = new Abarrotes(500,"Atun",1500,1000);
Abarrotes producto3 = new Abarrotes(1000,"Fideos", 990,1000);

abarrotes.add(producto1);
abarrotes.add(producto2);
abarrotes.add(producto3);

System.out.println(producto1.descripcion+ " " +producto1.precio);
System.out.println(producto2.descripcion+ " " +producto2.precio);
System.out.println(producto3.descripcion+ " " +producto3.precio);

int total, cantidad; 
String seleccion;
int pos = -1;


System.out.println("Escriba el prodcuto que desea");
seleccion = sc.nextLine();
for(int i=0; i<abarrotes.size();i++){
if (abarrotes.get(i).getDescripcion().equals(seleccion)){
pos=i;
}else{
    System.out.println("Elemento ingresado no valido");
}

if (pos!=-1){
    System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad");
cantidad = sc.nextInt();
total=cantidad*abarrotes.get(i).getPrecio();
System.out.println("Total: "+total);
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: La variable `pos` le estás asignando el índice.  En todo caso el `if` hazlo con ` >=0 y <array.size`

Comment: Buenas, Gaspar, bienvenido al sitio. Lo suyo es que le des una pensada. Efectivamente es con un bucle while, lo que tienes que determinar es que condición de salida debe tener ese bucle. Lo normal en este tipo de ejercicios es mostrarle un menu de opciones al usuario y que la última de ellas sea "salir" algo como "1-Editar nombre producto 2-Editar precio producto 3-Salir".

Comment: Por otro lado uno de los problemas que puede que tengas es que sc.nextInt no lee el salto de línea, así que después de ejecutarlo y realizar las operaciones que sean debes ejecutar un sc.nextLine para que lea ese caracter que se ha quedado ahí.

Comment: Gracias @RubioRic había olvidado lo del salto de lineal del sc.nextInt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaspar,

Tu planteamiento estaba bien, vas a necesitar un while para poder estar siempre en bucle y únicamente salir cuando el usuario quiera. Tienes que decidir cómo quieres que salga, yo te lo he puesto de manera que con poner "salir" cuando pida el producto, salga.
El problema que tienes de que te pide 3 veces es porque nextInt solo lee el número, no lee los intros. Entonces al poner luego un nextLine, lee el intro que ya metiste al meter el número y entonces ya salta de línea... Es un poco complicado de explicar en pocas palabras. Te paso lo que he hecho y le echas un vistazo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    List<Abarrote> abarrotes = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    abarrotes.add(new Abarrote(1000, "Arroz", 1300, 1000));
    abarrotes.add(new Abarrote(500, "Atun", 1500, 1000));
    abarrotes.add(new Abarrote(1000, "Fideos", 990, 1000));

    String inputText;

    //float para tener decimales 
    float total;
    int cantidad;
    
    //do while siempre hasta que escriba salir
    do {
        boolean existe = false;
        System.out.println("Escriba el producto que desea");
        inputText = sc.nextLine();  
        //si escribe salir, sale del while y termina
        if(inputText.equalsIgnoreCase("salir")) {
            break;
        }
        //for que recorre cada abarrote del array
        for(Abarrote abarrote : abarrotes) {
            //ignore case para que no tenga que preocuparse de mayus
            if(abarrote.getDescripcion().equalsIgnoreCase(inputText)) {
                existe = true;
                System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad");
                cantidad = sc.nextInt();
                total = cantidad * abarrote.getPrecio();
                System.out.println("Total: " + total);
                //esto es necesario para meter un intro
                sc.nextLine();
                //con el break sales del for 
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!existe) {
            //solo llegará aquí cuando no encuentre el producto
            System.out.println("¡El producto que ha introducido no existe!");
        }
    }while(true);
}
```

He hecho unos pequeños cambios: cambiar la clase en singular (las clases siempre en singular!!), he cambiado el for y utilizo un boolean para comprobar si existe, en vez de un int con -1. Otro consejo, tabula bien todo :p
Cualquier duda me dices.

Un saludo

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @MTM por tu tiempo y tu respuesta, la comprendí a la perfección, gracias por los tips además!